# Cannot inject angular cookies - Unknown provider error

Tags: angularjs, cookies

In my base controller I added `ngCookies`:

> var app = angular.module("MyApp", ["ui.router", "ngCookies"]);

Then in my Login controller that handles logins I did:

```
(function () {
    angular.module("MyApp").controller("LoginCtrl", ["$scope", "$state", "$http", "$cookies", MyLogin]);

    function MyLogin($scope, $state, $http, $cookies) {

    }

})();
```

And now I am getting an error:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $cookiesProvider <- $cookies <- LoginCtrl

I have references set for `angular-cookies.min.js`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/angular-cookies.min.js"</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have some problem with the scripts references because, as you can see in [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/gaveriv/edit?html,js,console), everything works well.

Debug your html code and see if the angular-cookies library it's correctly included ;)